# Why can't I use embedded resources (resx) when targeting .netstandard 1.3?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, csproj, project.json

(Question subtitle: Are resources not supported in `.netstandard 1.3` or is my project file just messed up?)

I just created an example portable class library in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 and added a sample resource file. Initially, the file `project.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "supports": {
    "net46.app": {},
    "uwp.10.0.app": {},
    "dnxcore50.app": {}
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore": "5.0.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility": "1.0.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "dotnet": {
      "imports": "portable-net452+win81"
    }
  }
}
```

Fine: No compile errors!

After that, I used the project properties to target `.NETStandard 1.3`.

[image: portable class library target]

Now `project.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "supports": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility": "1.0.1",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.3": {}
  }
}
```

Now I get the following build error - which means basically the the build action `EmbeddedRessource` is not supported:

[image: german error]

I'm really no expert with `project.json`, but for me the things look inconsistent - and I have no idea, where the problem is.

- in the first `project.json`: if I support `net46`, why is it importing `net452`?
- in the second `project.json`: if I use `netstandard1.3`, why is there a dependency to the library in version `1.6`?
- and finally, what is `.NETPortable, Version=v5.0`? The renaming of `.NET Core` has taken place early this year - why are we still referencing version `5.0`? Even [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh264221.aspx) doesn't know `<TargetFrameworkVersion>5.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>` which is specified in the `csproj`

For me, this seems like `netstandard` isn't only about the available libraries, tooling seems involved, too. But that does not explain, why it worked for `dnxcore50`.

Comment: I suspect that this has something to do with the fact that universal windows applications don't use `resx` files. But: universal windows apps are compatible with `netstandard 1.4` and higher...

Comment: you're right about resx part, but UWPs are actually compatible with `netstandard1.4` and lower not higher.

Comment: You are right, I looked at [the matrix](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md) and misunderstood the arrows. But it is even written there: _If a library targets .NET Platform Standard version 1.3, it can only run on .NET Framework 4.6 or later, .NET Core, Universal Windows Platform 10 (UWP), and Mono/Xamarin platforms._

Comment: @ventiseis You mean [The Most Unreadable and Awful Chart Ever Created In The History Of Mankind](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions.md)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need `Diagnostics.Tools` and `Resources.ResourceManager`.

I got this working (for .NET Standard 1.4 though) by installing the **pre** versions, at this time:

- "System.Diagnostics.Tools": "4.3.0-preview1-24530-04"
- "System.Resources.ResourceManager": "4.3.0-preview1-24530-04"

Comment: If I tries this again in an clean, new, up-to-date VS 2015 project, it actually works, after I installed the package `System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration` in the UWP app. But I'll mark your answer because you gave me the hint to install missing packages.

Comment: It seems Microsoft has created a new jungle of compatible and not-so-compatible packages, version numbers and dependencies which is not very easy to understand and manage if you're not a wizard of the new `.NET`-world. I hope this will be cleaned up and stabilized in the future.

Comment: I'm sure it will and glad u figured it out